# Conditional class not triggered by reactive shared store

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3, vue-directives

I have this `nav menu` which colors a menu item, when clicked:

[image]

At first I handled it with `state.active` by applying a `conditional class directive` like so:

**`component.vue`**:

```
<template>
  <div id="nav-v" class="nav-v">
    <ul>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'work'}" @click="resetState(0)" :class="{ colorize: state.active[0] }">Work</router-link></li>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'news'}" @click="resetState(1)" :class="{ colorize: state.active[1] }">News</router-link></li>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'newsletter'}" @click="resetState(2)" :class="{ colorize: state.active[2] }">Newsletter</router-link></li>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'about'}" @click="resetState(3)" :class="{ colorize: state.active[3] }">About</router-link></li>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'contact'}" @click="resetState(4)" :class="{ colorize: state.active[4] }">Contact</router-link></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import {reactive} from "vue";

const state = reactive({
    active: new Array(5).fill(false)
})

const resetState = (navLink) => {
    state.active.fill(false)
    state.active[navLink] = true
}
</script>
```

This works great. Whenever an item of `state.active` is true, the `colorize` class gets applied to the menu item, which basically sais `color: black`. In addition, whenever a menu item is clicked, the `resetState` function is applied, which resets all `state.active` objects to `false` before setting the clicked menu item to `true`.

But now I have to share `state.active` between components. As far as I know, the easiest way to do that is to create a `reactive shared store` and make it globally available:

**`js/store.js`**:

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

const store = reactive({})

export default {
    store
}
```

and then use it in the components like so:

**`component.vue`**:

```
<template>
  <div id="nav-v" class="nav-v">
    <ul>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'work'}" @click="resetState(0)" :class="{ colorize: store.active[0] }">Work</router-link></li>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'news'}" @click="resetState(1)" :class="{ colorize: store.active[1] }">News</router-link></li>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'newsletter'}" @click="resetState(2)" :class="{ colorize: store.active[2] }">Newsletter</router-link></li>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'about'}" @click="resetState(3)" :class="{ colorize: store.active[3] }">About</router-link></li>
      <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'contact'}" @click="resetState(4)" :class="{ colorize: store.active[4] }">Contact</router-link></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import store from "../../js/store";

store.active = new Array(5).fill(false)

const resetState = (navLink) => {
    store.active.fill(false)
    store.active[navLink] = true
    console.log(store.active)
}
</script>
```

This works great but for some reason it does not trigger the condition in:

```
:class="{ colorize: store.active[0] }"
```

Outputting `store.active` in the console shows the desired behaviour. Clicking on `Work` shows:

```
(5) [true, false, false, false, false]
```

while clicking on `News` shows:

```
(5) [false, true, false, false, false]
```

Why is the condition not triggered?

Comment: How if you change the `js/store.js` to include the active property? `const store = reactive({ active: new Array(5).fill(false)  })`

Comment: It's worth noting though, that you don't need to manually define classes. Vue Router has an active class and an exact-active class applied to `router-link`. Make sure to inspect the dom to see it.

Comment: @roliroli Oh wow, `router-link` has a dedicated class for this. Thank you